# android device to backup data on local server

Tags: android, web-services, rest, android-wifi

I am working on the android application that would perform functionality and ultimately save the data(Highly Confidential) in a local server, I am a newbie, I need ideas from you people in the shape of steps that i need to follow for the implementation. I cant expose the main main idea but the thing is store the customer data (in the database placed on server) on the server via android tablets, there will be multiple tablets feeding the data in parallel. I will appreciate if someone would suggest the appropriate tutorials (for webservice creation/usage etc)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [link](http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/) written by Roto Meier, it very well explains how you should back up the data.

**The following is an excerpt from it..**

*"The Backup Manager was added to Android in Froyo and it's about as trivial to implement as I can conceive.
All you need to do is extend the `BackupAgentHelper` and create a new `SharedPreferencesBackupHelper` within it's `onCreate` handler.
As shown in the PlacesBackupAgent, your Shared Preferences Backup Helper instance takes the name of your Shared Preference file, and you can specify the key for each of the preferences you want to backup. This should only be user specified preferences - it's poor practice to backup instance or state variables."*

```
public class PlacesBackupAgent extends BackupAgentHelper {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    SharedPreferencesBackupHelper helper = new 
      SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this, PlacesConstants.SHARED_PREFERENCE_FILE);
    addHelper(PlacesConstants.SP_KEY_FOLLOW_LOCATION_CHANGES, helper);
  }
}
```

*"To add your Backup Agent to your application you need to add an `android:backupAgent` attribute to the Application tag in your manifest."*

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:backupAgent="PlacesBackupAgent">
```

*"You also need to specify an API key (which you can obtain from here: http://code.google.com/android/backup/signup.html)"*

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.backup.api_key" 
           android:value="Your Key Goes Here" />
```

*"To trigger a backup you just tell the Backup Manager that the data being backed up has changed. I do this within the `SharedPreferenceSaver` classes, starting with the `*FroyoSharedPreferenceSaver*`."*

```
public void savePreferences(Editor editor, boolean backup) {
  editor.commit();
  backupManager.dataChanged();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the effort but i dun think its an appropriate answer to what I have asked, its not that I am saving the user data but to save the "Customers" data :)

Comment: well your question reads backup data on a local server so that was my answer. Anyways what is that you actually want to do?

Comment: Actually I am looking for storing and retrieving data from a local server on my tablet :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a ton of HTTP Based services frameworks,  and almost every pure java framework
(like CXF,  Axis etc.) client will run on android - you just have to pick one that sucks less (this is hard part) and is easier to handle.

For confidential and sensitive data  I would use encrypted channels - but this is framework
independent.